# Why was Christine Brown not taken to hell on the third Day?

Tags: plot-explanation, drag-me-to-hell

In 2009's film [Drag Me to Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_Me_to_Hell) by Sam Raimi, as Christine never got success in beating Lamia , why was she not taken to hell on the third day(As per three day curse rule). I know that on third day San Dena was killed in fighting Lamia but that did not remove the curse and even Christine gave the wrong envelope to Dead Ganush. So she is still the owner of the button. So why did not Lamia  take Christine's soul on Third day

Why to wait for forth day morning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I recall correctly, it was on the *third day* that Christine tried to pass the curse onto the old woman by stuffing the envelope into her dead mouth. However, as we all know, it was the wrong envelope.

Christine and her boyfriend are at the station the following morning when all is revealed, and Christine is dragged down into the ground between the tracks. So she was indeed taken to hell, and perhaps it is possible that three days had not expired (thinking in terms of 72 hours) when this takes place, as the curse was placed on her mid-morning on the first day.

Comment: You defeated me in typing! +1 for that! :)

Comment: Yes you are right , its third day when she gave wrong envelope to the old lady. Thanx for correcting my fact and may be your 72 hour logic is correct.